# JavaScript Behavior Inconsistency

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle, twitch

I seem to be having a little problem with my JavaScript: it works as expected on JSFiddle, but not when opened from a local `.html` file.

Here's the code as it is on my hard disk:

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        window.onPlayerLoad = function () {
            alert("test");
        };
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <object bgcolor='#000000' data='http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/archive_embed_player.swf' height='378' id='clip_embed_player_flash' type='application/x-shockwave-flash' width='620'>
        <param name='movie' value='http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/archive_embed_player.swf'>
        <param name='allowScriptAccess' value='always'>
        <param name='allowNetworking' value='all'>
        <param name='allowFullScreen' value='true'>
        <param name='flashvars' value='title=IEM%2BSingapore&amp;channel=esltv_sc2&amp;auto_play=false&amp;start_volume=25&amp;archive_id=484099469&amp;initCallback=onPlayerLoad'>
    </object>
</body>

</html>
```

And here it is on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/77Bpa/.

The purpose of this code is to load a Twitch player and call a function once it has finished loading. The function that should be called is `window.onPlayerLoad`, and it is passed to the flash object through the `initCallback` flashvar (see the [Twitch Player API](https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API/blob/master/player.md)).

And so, on JSFiddle the alert pops up as expected, however when I open the file locally there is no such effect. Both Firefox and Internet Explorer say that `window.onPlayerLoad` exists, but it is not getting called.

What might be the cause of this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It works for me. Maybe you should wait for a second because loading takes a second or two.

Comment: I see that you have delated the function as window.onPlayerLoad but your callback is just onPlayerLoad. I would try to make those agree.

Comment: @lukasz1985, I did wait for several seconds, the player finished loading and still no alert box. @bitfiddler: tried it, didn't work. It's actually how the official documentation says to do it (declare as `window.onPlayerLoad`, pass to object as `onPlayerLoad`).

Comment: First: it may not help bu try to do "var onPlayerLoad = ... " instead of "window.onPlayerLoad = ...". Second, more possible - check it using something like "console.log("test")" and watch the site load with browser console open on JavaScript debugging. At least - try to insert breakpoint using browser. The callback may still be workin - but something could be screwed up with loading files from local filesystem in your browser.

Comment: @lukasz1985, tried setting up a breakpoint both before the callback declaration and inside the callback. The one before the declaration gets triggered, but the one inside does not. Also, replacing `window.onPlayerLoad` with `var onPlayerLoad` has no effect.

Comment: The issue seems to be that you are accessing the page from local filesystem, with the file:// protocol. This doesn't work, as I've discovered now. You should create a host and access it via the http://

Comment: Wow. It worked. Never would have thought of that. Thanks, @lukasz1985. If you'll write an answer, I'll flag it as accepted.

Comment: Well, such issuess are usually are the last resort. I will give an answer to this question, so it wont hang in the air, but feel free to change the accepted answer if somebody will come with in depth explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in my comment the issue is that the flash doesn't invoke callback because of some, unknown to me reason - related to the protocols used in request of the page that it is used on. Using http:// over file:// solves the issue. So simply uploading or using local host to request a page with the player works fine and fails when loading a html file into browser from local filesystem.